# How to create openshift application for OPENSHIFT ONLINE 3 STARTER (NEW!) server in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, jboss-tools

I am trying to create an openshift3 application in Eclipse IDE after installing JBoss Developer tool plugin in IDE, But getting below error at the time Sign into OpenShift.

Error: ***The server type, credentials, or auth scheme might be incorrect***:

[image: OpenShift credentials]

I have also tried other server hostname like `https://console.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com/console/` and much more, but still not working.

While, when I tried to log in using OC tool (OpenShift CLI) with the same credential (as seen in picture), I haven't got any error.

I also tried to run RHC (OpenShift Client Tool) but at the time of RHC setup it is saying *"You are not authorized to perform this operation."*

Please help me to solve it out.

Comment: The ``rhc`` command line tool is for OpenShift 2, not OpenShift 3. The OpenShift 3 command line tool is ``oc``.

Comment: Thank you to reply, but how to login to openshift 3 server using eclipse?

Comment: What are the options for authentication protocol? I doubt 'Basic' will work. You want one which takes a token, which you obtain from https://console.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com/console/command-line or by running ``oc whoami -t``.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you're using an outdated version of the JBoss Tools Openshift plugin, because the "New Openshift Application" wizard looks a little bit different at the moment. So try to update it:

*Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Update...* - and choose at least all the JBoss Tools plugins that it'll report to you (the best will be to choose everything reported) and update them.

Secondly, what is the URL which you use to access the Openshift web console in your browser? It seems to me that it is `https://console.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com`. Are you able to login there with your credentials? If yes, the same must work in JBoss Tools Openshift plugin. Check [this](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/04/10/develop-and-deploy-on-openshift-next-gen-using-red-hat-jboss-developer-studio/) and [this](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/04/28/develop-and-deploy-on-openshift-next-gen-using-red-hat-jboss-developer-studio-part-2/) articles for more info about using it.